# Does construction of a Lightsaber require use of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, lightsaber

It's true that Lightsaber construction is a mandatory skill for a trained Force user, but I am not sure about it in reverse.

@DVK has commented on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26829/931) that:

> Grievous wasn't a Jedi (or a Force Sensitive) at all. He couldn't construct one.

I always thought that a Lightsaber was a normal piece of technology which even non-Force users could construct, and you only need Force sensitivity to master  Lightsaber skills. But, I could be wrong.

Does construction of a Lightsaber require use of the Force? If yes, what role does the Force play in the construction of a Lightsaber?

Comment: In one of the latest Clone War episodes, the younglings have to find crystals for their lightsaber. IIRC all of the younglings had to use the force in some way to retrieve the crystals. Thus, yes, construction of a lightsaber requires the use of the force.... from a certain point of view ;-)

Comment: One of the novels states that a new sith orders sabers can only be activated by the force no switches were installed the time where hans and leias kids were placed in there training camp with lobacca

Comment: I assumed there were energized parts of a light saber that you simply couldn't pick up with your hands (burn your fingers off) so only a force user levitating and maneuvering parts was able to properly and safely assemble one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the Return of the Jedi novel where Luke constructs his first lightsaber, he uses the force to detect imperfections in the crystals and how to align them perfectly in the lightsaber. Technically, the force is not required to build a lightsaber. It's just a ritual part of the Jedi training to become intimately familiar with the weapon and how all the components fit together.

In one of the Timothy Zahn novels, I recall Luke saying that in his research, Jedi in the clone wars were able to speed up the construction process and build a lightsaber within a day during a time of crisis when the weapon was more important than the ritual (which took considerably longer than a day).

> Ideally, a Jedi took many months to construct a single perfect weapon
>   that he or she would keep and use for a lifetime. Once you build it,
>   the lightsaber will become your constant companion, your tool, and a
>   ready means of defense.

While anyone can build them as they are just pieces of technology, not everyone can handle them. In most cases, force training is required to properly handle the weapon. Which is why not everyone has them (that, and the Jedi and Sith tend not to share the building plans with non-Jedi/Sith).

As for Grevious, the lightsabers were trophies.

Comment: In one of the NJO novels Anikin tells a YV that the process of building the lightsaber is more important that the components used.

Comment: Grevious used them, trophies or not.  So that 'anyone' could handle them if not build them.

Comment: Also, in legends, in the game KOTOR 2 your non jedi companion builds a lightsaber for the player character, then again, you can train him to be a jedi so maybe it's not the best example.

Comment: Finn uses a lightsabre in The Force Awakens and he's not force trained.But then I think we need to make a distinction between "using them" and "using them well". Finn did get his ass handed to him, after all.

Comment: @Oldcat And you think Grevious is 'anyone'?

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

From that prolific source of information, Lucasfilm’s Pablo Hidalgo:

[image]

As to why….

The Force is necessary in order to align the kyber crystals in precisely the right manner.

> The lightsaber wouldn’t work properly now
>   , even if I put it back
>   together; without proper focusing there was no telling what would
>   happen if I tried to turn it on. It might explode. And aligning those
>   crystals by hand would be impossible—I sensed that it had to be done
>   with the Force, and only through the Force would I know whether it was
>   aligned properly or not. They were wafer-thin slices of crystal, too,
>   a beautiful clear amethyst, and might scratch or cloud with handling.
>   Moving them precisely with the Force would ensure that they remained
>   pristine.
>
> <sub>*Heir to the Jedi*</sub>

Note that this is not merely a matter of fine manipulation (which might, with difficulty, be achieved by machine). The Force is necessary to know when the kyber crystals are aligned, which makes sense in light of the semi-sentience of kyber crystals, as discussed in *Ahsoka* and *Catalyst*.

That said, it might not be entirely *impossible*. The difficulties that Grievous would have faced are exemplified by what Galen Erso had to deal with when trying to use kyber crystals in the construction of the Death Star, but Erso eventually succeeded.

Answer (score 6):

The costruction of a lightsaber needed to be done by a trained Force user due to the fact that if the crystal was placed incorrectly it would explode when activated. This is why a lightsaber was constructed traditionaly away from anyone else except the Jedi/Sith that was building it. Sith, from my understanding, didn't always create their first lightsaber as it was an award given by their masters for passing the training on Korriban. However, they more than often used synthesized red crystals that had no tarnishes or deformaties. A good example is when Sidious gave Vader one for his new Sith lightsaber. In order for a non Force user to wield a lightsaber is a different story as even the sarcastic Han Solo used Luke's if only briefly to cut open a Tauntaun for warmth. Grievous also was not a force user, however, he was trained to use them and because of his constructed body, had borderline Jedi like reflexes.

Comment: Welcome Darth Solace. Who is your master?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Star Wars Visual Dictionary, it was only through great mastery of The Force that the irregular crystal could be properly aligned. If this was not done precisely and correctly, then when the Lightsaber was turned on for the first time, it would explode, killing the maker. Thus, building a Lightsaber is the ultimate "final exam". Only when this has been done successfully, as Vader said to Luke, can one truly be a Jedi.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the [Star Wars Expanded Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Expanded_Universe) mention that lightsaber construction requires use of the Force. Various reasons are given. It's more a matter of tradition rather than necessity to build one's lightsaber with the Force. Often it is so that the Jedi can create a customized weapon that perfectly fits their needs and techniques. Also, Force handling is often required when aligning the crystal in the weapon. In some stories, this is because an improperly aligned crystal could malfunction, causing the weapon to either explode or not work at all.

Answer (score -2):

in some stories its says that a Jedi/Sith must force meditate over their crystal for an extended period of time to imbue them with properties compatible with a lightsaber. also some accounts suggest that they use the force to bind components together on a molecular level.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Please could you add some sources to improve this answer?

Answer (score -2):

It's safe to say it doesn't, the fact that a non force user can activate a lightsaber means no need of the force to build one. Ezra built one and he was only a recent padawan who'd yet develop the essential skills. Presumably the force is used to precisely augment the crystal, a circumstance a Sith don't need given they use synthetic ones. Energy weapons similar to lightsabers. Electrified laser blades (Clone Wars: The Box), energy whips (Episode: Slaves of the Republic) are similar tech and they presumably don't require force sensitive people to build them.

Comment: The Sith using synthetic crystals is no longer part of the Star Wars canon; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Synthetic_kyber_crystal. Laser blades and Energy whips don't appear to use kyber crystals. Ezra used the force when building his first lightsaber. Aside from that...